# How would I fit this linear trend function in R?

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, trend

I want to fit this linear trend function to my data:

Y<sub>t</sub>=a+bt+X<sub>t</sub>

This is based on time series data.
I believe writing `lm(y ~ time)` will return the equivalent of Y<sub>t</sub>=a+X<sub>t</sub> but I'm confused how to include bt into this linear trend function in R.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply include it as an explanatory variable

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(id = 1)
d <- d[, .(year=1:200), by=id]
d[, x1 := runif(200)]

# add an erros
d[, e := rnorm(200, 23, 7)]

# add the dependent variable
d[, y := 3.5*x1 + 0.5*year + e  ]

m <- lm(y ~ x1 + year, d)
summary(m)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + year, data = d)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-19.2008  -4.4356   0.3986   5.2283  16.6819 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 20.064776   1.519766  13.203   <2e-16 ***
x1           3.114048   1.914318   1.627    0.105    
year         0.523195   0.009187  56.947   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.469 on 197 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.943, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9424 
F-statistic:  1628 on 2 and 197 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```